# Set/Change property with dynamic name using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So when I try to set up a property name/value pair, I'm not sure what the property name will be. It will depend on a meta data node.

Two metadata nodes:

```
{ id:1, value:'name' }
{ id:2, value:'age' }
```

I need to add a property for a Person node but I don't want to use condition statement (and cypher does not have condition statement). I want something like:

```
if (metadata.id = 1) {
    set person.name = 'xx'
} else if (metadata.id = 2) {
    set person.age = 'xx'
}
```

or:

```
match (m:metadata{id:1}), (p:person{id:1}) set p.'m.value' = 'xx'
```

I don't want to use the `if / else` condition statement. Is there a cypher condition statement, or how can this be achieved?

Comment: I don't want to use condition statement (and cypher does not have condition statement).

Comment: Thanks for responses. I'm sorry for the vague description

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are getting at, but take a look at parameterized Cypher queries. Docs [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html) and [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-cypher-parameters-java.html)

Comment: Cypher does have a conditional statement: [Case expressions](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-expressions.html#query-syntax-case). But I don't think you can use it for control flow, as you seem to want to.

Comment: Parameters would work, but something without REST API and java would be better since I'm newbie and i'm using neo4jshell

Answer (score 2):

You can use `WHERE` for filtering on conditions

```
MATCH (p:Person) WHERE p.age > 21 SET p.drunk = true
```

or you can use a `CASE` expression to generate a zero or one-element list that you then can use with `FOREACH`

```
MATCH (p:Person) 
WITH p, (case when p.age > 21 then [1] else [] end) as drunk_filter
FOREACH (x in drunk_filter | SET p.drunk = true)
```

Foreach has the advantage that the query continues after that.